# Which output styles remove multiline line comments?

Tags: comments, sass

In an SCSS file, which output style(s) ([nested, expanded, compact or compressed](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#output_style)) will remove multiline (`/* I'm a comment. */`) comments from the final CSS?

Comment: Try them and find out?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`:compressed` is the only output style which will remove multi-line (`/* ... */`) comments from the final rendered CSS.

Additionally, :compact will turn a multi-line comment into a single line in the final CSS. With :nested and :expanded, all multi-line comments and their line breaks are rendered in the final CSS.

For example, this SCSS:

```
// SL Comment

/* ML Comment1
   Whoop. */

//! SL w/ bang

/*! ML Comment2
    Whoop. */
```

will become the following CSS for each different output style:

Nested:

```
/* ML Comment1
   Whoop. */
/* ML Comment2  
    Whoop. */
```

Expanded:

```
/* ML Comment1
   Whoop. */
/* ML Comment2
    Whoop. */
```

Compact:

```
/* ML Comment1 Whoop. */
/* ML Comment2 
    Whoop. */
```

Compressed:

```
/* ML Comment2
    Whoop. */
```

Beginning a comment with `!` only affects multi-line comments in `:compressed` mode, where they will be preserved when they would otherwise be removed from the final CSS.

Comment: If you're using scssphp (http://leafo.net/scssphp/) this is not the case. Multi-line comments are not removed regardless of the output formatter.

Answer (score 4):

Even with output style "compressed", I have not been able to remove multi-line comments, and the sass/scss documentation also suggests that they are not removed (only single-line comments with "//" are removed).

My solution was to simply apply a Perl one-liner to manually remove comments from a .css file, after sass has generated its final output:

```
sass -fCE utf-8 -t compressed application.sass application.css
perl -pi -e'BEGIN{$/=undef}s#/\*.*?\*/##gs' application.css
```

Answer (score 4):

It's a shame I can't downvote or comment on the accepted answer. As per the doc's, what was written and accepted is simply untrue. Sass only removes single line codes and preserves multiline comments.

> Sass supports standard multiline CSS comments with /* */, as well as single-line comments with //. The multiline comments are preserved in the CSS output where possible, while the single-line comments are removed.

[See here for the docs.](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#Comments________and_____comments)

Comment: As of today's date, 'compressed' *does* remove multiline comments.